# Laravel ORM with filter

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here are my tables in DB:

posts: id,group,creator,body,hide

like_user_post_relationships: id,user,post

Model:LikeUserPostRelationship:

user belongsTo(User::class,'user')

post belongsTo(Post::class,'post')

How do I query all `LikeUserPostRelationship::Where('user','=',$user->id)->with('post')->get();` 
And filter out the LikeUserPostRelationship collection with $post->hide = true?

appreciate any help!

Comment: Like user posts looks like it should be a many to many relationship, it shouldn't have a model and belongsToMany should be used in User and Post.

Comment: yes i am still learning, will explore on many to many relationship

Comment: how should the many to many relationships be for the like post?

Comment: Read laravel.com/docs.  They have it pretty  well documented.

Comment: I have been trying the hasMany relation from User model to LikeUserPostRelationship, I can be able to do this: $query=User::find(Auth::id())->first(); return $query->like_post; but i am unable to do return $query->like_post->post; Error saying there is no collection called [post]. I have already defined post relationship in LikeUserPostRelationship model.

Comment: i am able to resolve the issue with Auth::user()->like_post()->whereDoesntHave('post', function($query){$query->where('hide','=',true)})->with('post')->get();

Comment: You still shouldn't have a model for relationships.   Like I said above, it's a many to many relationship, look at the docs on how to deal with those.  Can users really only like one post?  I doubt it, so using $user->like_post as a single item isn't right.

Comment: Thank you, Devon, Many to Many relationships is a life saver! The problem I faced as a new laravel developer is the multiple types of relationships intermediary is needed and it is pretty confusing: post_user_like table, post_user_share. So the custom tagging is very useful here!

Comment: Yeah, well those are both just one type of relationship, many-to-many.  Many-to-many relationships are the only ones that need the intermediate table.   If it was one-to-many or one-to-one, you'd just store the id in one of the existing tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `whereDoesntHave()` for your criteria which will filter out the results where related post is set as hide = true

```
$results = LikeUserPostRelationship::with('post')
                        ->where('user','=',$user->id)
                        ->whereDoesntHave('post', function ($query) {
                            $query->where('hide', '=', true);
                        })
                        ->get();
```

[See *Querying Relationship Absence*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)